# Connecting to OpenVPN 2 factor via network manager

Tags: 16.04, vpn

I have been trying to figure out if there is a way to connect to an openvpn network using 2FA through the network manager in ubuntu.

Using the console I can connect and get the request for the 2FA code, but when trying to configure via the GUI it never asks for the 2FA code.

Grepping /var/syslog just shows the vpn asking for the google authenticator code, but I never receive the popup.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like support for two-factor authentication has been added to the `network-manager-openvpn` plugin as of version 1.2.10, released on May 17, 2017. (mentioned as `support for dynamic challenge-response protocol` in [the `NEWS` file](https://git.gnome.org/browse/network-manager-openvpn/tree/NEWS#n9) and [the corresponding commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/network-manager-openvpn/commit/?id=5b96fecb97c752e08fdcebb331b983196f4b8935), and tracked by [this issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751842))

However, it doesn't look like that version is available on any Ubuntu release currently, and I can't seem to find an up-to-date PPA for it, so you'll likely have to build it yourself in order to get it working.

In the meantime, you can use the `openvpn` command-line client; it will actually ask you for the 2FA code interactively, if your `.ovpn` file is set up correctly.

Comment: I've installed it from sources, made it to appear in a network-manager, but there is no place in UI where it asks for challenge response. Looks like at [this moment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1322728) you can't use UI to connect.